# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.( http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/student/find/subject?page=2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Hi all developer do you have any idea with my error ,I tried to use paginate with query "LIKE" select statement in laravel 7 , everything is ok but when try to click on page 2 or move to next page I'm got the error message

Thank you

```
**My error message **
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
( http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/student/find/subject?page=2)
```

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $par = $request->input('search');
        $result = DB::table('tbl_couse_title')->select()
                    ->where('del','=','N')
                    ->where('couse_type', 'LIKE' , '%' .$par. '%')
                    ->orWhere('page_name','LIKE', '%'.$par.'%')
                  
                    ->paginate(2);
         
        return view('students.stu_list_search',compact('result'));  
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/stu_index','students\Dashboard_students@index')->name('stu_index')->middleware('student');
Route::post('students/student/find/subject','students\student_search_index@index')->name('stu_list_search')->middleware('student');
```

Blade

```
    <label for="result" class="mt-2" style="float:right;">Result:10</label><br />
    @foreach($result as $row)
        <div class="list-group mt-3 mb-3">
            <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img src="{{asset('assets/img/kanann.jpg')}}" class="rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                            <h5 class="mb-1">{{$row->page_name}}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <p class="mb-1">{{$row->couse_type}}</p>
                        <small class="text-muted">Contact</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align:right;padding-top:25px;">
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>Detail</button></a>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{ $result ->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use post method in web.php file.
Change to get.

```
Route::post('students/student/find/subject','students\student_search_index@index')->name('stu_list_search')->middleware('student')
```

To

```
Route::get('students/student/find/subject','students\student_search_index@index')->name('stu_list_search')->middleware('student')
```

Comment: Thank for your help , but after changed Route get then i got error when i'm filter data from textbox like this "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Answer (score 1):

Laravel pagination links need the GET method to retrieve data, but since you want to be able to send search input you can use:

```
Route::any('students/student/find/subject','students\student_search_index@index')->name('stu_list_search')->middleware('student');
```

Comment: @Majdien Thank you very much for you help , I'm already followed you , and now it worked perfect .